# PDFBox processing page by page still gives OutOfMemoryError in Java

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am using PDFBox to extract text from a PDF file and insert those text as words into the database table.

It works perfectly fine. However, when I try to load a bigger file which has 10 million words, it throws `OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`.

So what I did was I instead of processing the whole file, I process the file page by page so it should occupies less memory.

This is how it looks like:

processtext method:

```
  public void processText(String text) throws SQLException {

        String lines[] = text.split("\\r?\\n");
        for (String line : lines) {
            String[] words = line.split(" ");


            String sql="insert IGNORE into  test.indextable values (?,?);";


            preparedStatement = con1.prepareStatement(sql);
            int i=0;
            for (String word : words) {

                // check if one or more special characters at end of string then remove OR
                // check special characters in beginning of the string then remove
                // insert every word directly to table db
                word=word.replaceAll("([\\W]+$)|(^[\\W]+)", "");
                preparedStatement.setString(1, path1);
                preparedStatement.setString(2, word);



                preparedStatement.addBatch();

                i++;
                if (i % 1000 == 0) {
                    preparedStatement.executeBatch();

                    System.out.print("Add Thousand");
                }




            }




            if (i > 0) {
                preparedStatement.executeBatch();

                System.out.print("Add Remaining");

            }

        }
        preparedStatement.close();
        System.out.println("Successfully commited changes to the database!");

    }
```

index() method calling the above method :

```
 public void index() throws Exception {
       // Connection con1 = con.connect();
        try {

            // Connection con1=con.connect();
           // Connection con1 = con.connect();
            Statement statement = con1.createStatement();

            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from filequeue where Status='Active' LIMIT 5");


            while (rs.next()) {
                // get the filepath of the PDF document
                 path1 = rs.getString(2);
               int getNum = rs.getInt(1);
                // while running the process, update status : Processing
                //updateProcess_DB(getNum);
                Statement test = con1.createStatement();
                test.executeUpdate("update filequeue SET STATUS ='Processing' where UniqueID="+getNum);



                try {
                    // call the index function


                    /*Indexing process = new Indexing();

                    process.index(path1);*/

                    PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(path1));

                    if (!document.isEncrypted()) {

                        PDFTextStripper tStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
                        for(int p=1; p<=document.getNumberOfPages();++p) {
                            tStripper.setStartPage(p);
                            tStripper.setEndPage(p);
                            String pdfFileInText = tStripper.getText(document);
                            processText(pdfFileInText);

                        }


                        }
```

Did a test again on that file and it seems it still throws the same error. I am clearly out of ideas as to how I could fix this.

Comment: When is the OOM happening, could you include the stack trace? Does it also happening when trying to reduce the example, e.g. not inserting? How many pages are processed? Does it happen after a certain amount of files, or can you reproduce it with a single file, i.e. when hardcoding that only "the one" file is processed? What PDFBox version are you using?

Comment: What is your -Xmx value / have you tried to increase it? Also check whether the version of the jdbc driver is the latest.

Comment: After reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53551335/ - if it fails at loading time, then the whole question is kindof moot.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Yea my jdbc driver is latest and XMX is set to 1024mb, I did try to increase it but no success. pdfbox version is 2.0

Comment: It's throwing the error in PDD Document when it tries to load the file, as you linked the question above, that is the question i posted

Comment: If the oom happens while loading the pdf, optimizing the steps after loading don't help in any way. You might try to load using a different memory usage for pdfbox but most likely you will have to give more memory to java.

Comment: @mkl Yes it won't help in any way. The first step is to load the file regardless either way right?

Comment: "pdfbox version is 2.0" - there are 12 different 2.0 versions. The latest is 2.0.12 and soon 2.0.13. Make sure you're using 2.0.12 and not lower. And yes you'll have to increase -Xmx. Try -Xmx4g or even more.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I just double checked, it's pdfbox-2.0.12 . I am sure that's fine

Comment: Yes that is good. (I had to ask. There are often people who come up with versions several years old)

Comment: So in my case, I don't really have any choice since I have to use "load" . I don't think increase the memory -XMX helps either. I did try that some time ago

Comment: Yeah it sounds like you're really f*cked. An idea would be to try PDFSam https://pdfsam.org/ . That is a PDFBox fork that can do "parse on demand". I wonder if that one can open the file. If yes, then you could try to split it and save. But the API is not published AFAIK, so you would have to look at the source code.

Comment: I see. What do you mean parse on demand?

Comment: "parse on demand" means to parse PDF objects only when/if they are accessed. This would save memory.