# Java- Does pdfBox have an option to open file instead of loading it?

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am using PDFBox in Java to attempt to extract text from the pdf file. This is how I load the file:

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(path1));
```

As you can see, it opens the file and loads the stuff inside it. This may cause issue when say I tried to load a file which has 10 million words or text which is huge and it throws an `OutOfMemoryException:Java heap space`.

I actually tested this and it does throw an error. And the culprit was the line above. 
Is there a way to open the file but not loading it's content in PDFBox?

I appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Use :

```
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(file, MemoryUsageSetting.setupTempFileOnly());
```

This will setup buffering memory usage to only use temporary files with no restricted size.

Comment: Then give more memory to your jeans process.

Comment: @mkl I tried going beyond it and it doesn't help. The issue here is it throws the error when it tries to call doc.load without even processsing the file yet

Comment: Can you test on a different computer that has a lot of memory, e.g. 64GB? If yes, then download pdfbox-app and try opening with that one with different high XMX values to see what is needed.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr It's okay, adding -Xmx 1024m seems to help in VM options.